# Thread Pool Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am working on changing legacy design with Thread Pool Executor. The details are as follows:-

Legacy:- In case of legacy design 600 threads are created at the time of application start up.
and are placed in various pools, which are then picked up when required and task is assigned to the corresponding thread.

New:- In new design i replaced the thread pool by executor service as

```
 ThreadPoolExecutor thpool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(coreSize,poolsize,...);
```

What i am observing is that in case of Executor no threads are created at the time of start up. They are created when request is fired from the client. As a result of which threads created in memory are quite less as compared to previous one.

But what my question is that is it right way because Thread creation is also a overhead which is happening at the time of call is triggered.

Please tell which is more heavy, process Thread creation at the time of call from client or Idle threads being there in memory as per legacy approach.

Also suggest which Executor pool to use in order to get best results in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

to fix 600 threads at start-up, try to use [java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 600 );](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29)

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
>   off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads
>   will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted
>   when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a
>   thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during
>   execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed
>   to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until
>   it is explicitly shutdown.

As you can read, the documentation doesn't tell us if the threads are started immediately or on demand.

If you want absolutely the 600 threads started at start-up you may post 600 empty tasks:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 600; ++i ) {
   executor.submit( new Runnable(){public void run(){/**/}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call :

```
thpool.prestartAllCoreThreads();
```

or

```
thpool.prestartCoreThread();
```

This two methods to Starts a core thread (Threads), causing it to idly wait for work.

But i recommended do not do this, it's will be head over on your resources.

Answer (score 0):

600 sounds like a lot. You may want to lower this somewhat, to the number of available processors. Or, if the threads end up waiting a lot, factor in the average load incurred be the TPE's `Runnables`, if your threads are not 100% CPU-bound. Say you have `nCPUs=Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` and `loadFactor` as your average load on your threads (as observed in testing or, better yet, continuous monitoring). Then you would use nThreads=nCPUs/loadFactor and hope that loadFactor is not zero.

You can also use a smaller coresize and larger poolsize, but then you need a bounded queue. The TPE in this case would start up new threads if the queue is full, until you reach poolsize. If the majority of your jobs is handled within coresize, thread creation should not be too frequent and overhead should not be a concern. But even this may block eventually when TPE has its maximum threads running.

If your jobs are some kind of incoming work, like read from a socket of other connection that must not block, you can create an unbounded intermediate queue to free inbound processing from eventually blocking at your TPE, and use another thread to submit jobs from intermediate to the TPE queue.

Comment: How do we calculate number of threads required u guess we have a formula :-

Number of CPU * Performance throughput * (1+W/C) where W is wait time and C is desired computation time .

Please tell me in detail how to get the number of threads required.

Comment: Not sure what your _Performance throughput_ is, but see my edit.

Comment: Hi Ralf,

Thanks for the input. Well but i have entered into a fix.
I have created a ThreadPoolExecutor with core size as maxpoolsize/5 and using LinkedBlockingQueue as queue.

I have invoked method "prestartAllCoreThreads" which starts all core Threads roughly around 170 threads on startup.

Comment: The reason i did this was that when i fired request from client executor created new thread which was consuming time so wanted to eliminate this option.

But this approach has backfired on me. The memory consumption has increased as compared to legacy code which was there also i cant find and significant improvement in performance regarding processing of request.

Comment: Regarding task from client is should tell u that what i am doing is that from client i am giving a device IP to which server then sends a RMI command. THe task is assigned a thread from thread pool which i have created.

Please tell me where i have made a fault in my approach and how to optimize this behavior using Executors.

Thanks & Regards,
Tushar

Comment: so the server takes RMI calls, wraps them in Callables and lets the TPE execute them, then waits for the Future.get() and returns the results via RMI? And since the RMI calls are synchronous, you must have one thread for each concurrent RMI call?